# How to create single log file in uwsgi?

Tags: django, logging, uwsgi

I’m using below uwsgi logging config file for Django application. Its creating two log files:

1. access_log-2023-10-13.log
2. app_log-2023-10-13.log

Now I want to create one more log file named **all_logs-2023-10-13.log** which will have both `access + app` log file data. Is there any way to create this?

```
[uwsgi]
master = true
http-socket = xyz_port
memory-report = true
module = demo_app.wsgi
...
...
...

log-date = %%d/%%m/%%Y %%H:%%M:%%S %%Z
logformat-strftime = true
logger = stdio
log-format = %(addr) - %(user) [%(ftime)] "%(method) %(uri) %(proto)" %(status) %(size) %(referer) %(uagent) %(pid)
req-logger = file:/var/log/demo_app/access_log-@(exec://date +%%Y-%%m-%%d).log
logger = file:/var/log/demo_app/app_log-@(exec://date +%%Y-%%m-%%d).log
log-reopen = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [uWSGI documentation](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html) outlines the use of `--log-route` for directing log messages based on regular expressions to different destinations.
However, it does not provide a direct method to combine logs from different sources into a single file.

You would need to create a simple script to merge the log files, which can be scheduled to run daily to merge the `access_log` and `app_log` into `all_logs`.

Something like:

```py
import datetime

def merge_logs():
    date_suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    with open(f'/var/log/demo_app/access_log-{date_suffix}.log', 'r') as access_log, \
         open(f'/var/log/demo_app/app_log-{date_suffix}.log', 'r') as app_log, \
         open(f'/var/log/demo_app/all_logs-{date_suffix}.log', 'a') as all_logs:
        for line in access_log:
            all_logs.write(line)
        for line in app_log:
            all_logs.write(line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    merge_logs()
```

> But my log files are getting compressed on daily basis using log rotation. So, would it be a good idea to create manual script for all_logs?

Then the script can be scheduled daily, *before* the log rotation/compression, in order to produce an `all_logs.20xxMMJJ` every day.

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful. But my log files are getting compressed on daily basis using log rotation. So, would it be a good idea to create manual script for all_logs?

Comment: @AkashPagar I have edited the answer to address your comment.